# Owl carousel 2.2 stopped autoplay after minimize and maximize the browser screen

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I am facing the issue in owl carousel, auto rotation of images gets stopped when we minimize and maximize the screen. This issue also re-produced on the demo site of the plug-in as you can see in the link:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html

**Step to reproduce:**
1- open the link
2- minimize the browser screen
3- maximize the browser screen
4- now its stops

Comment: Facing same issue on Owl Carousel 2.